# Magento scope levels: no [STORE] scope?

Tags: scope

I would like to ask, what sort of logic caused the developers of Magento to include [GLOBAL], [WEBSITE], and [STORE VIEW] scopes but not [STORE] scopes as well. Why does it make sense to exclude the [STORE] scope from the scopes appearing on the

```
System -> Configuration
```

magento admin panel page?

Answer (score 2):

I think the `[STORE]` does not exist as a scope because the `store` entity is just a way of grouping store views.
[Here is a detailed explanation by Fabrizio Branca on what you can do for each scope](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-website-store-groups-store-views.html)
Off topic: Honestly I've never used that in my life. Always 'one store per website' and 'multiple store views for the same store'.

Comment: I agree with @Marius.  Its a placeholder for store views. The label is mainly for internal use on the admin.  From what I recall, its not displayed to the public in any fashion, for example emails, or on the front end for customers to see.  Its a way to separate and show groups of store views in the magento admin for drop down menus, etc.